# How to hide the new title bar in youtube embeds?

Tags: youtube, embed

I have a page with embedded youtube videos.

[image]

As of today, apparently, there are these new title bars on videos with the Watch Later and Share icons which kind of ruin everything. Already having the play button wasn't that great, but now showinfo=0 doesn't seem to work anymore. Google hasn't helped. :(

Anyone know how to get rid of it, or have a link to new API docs?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was something on their end that they've since resolved.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem resolved.  When logged in to google I'm seeing title, subscribe, comments, video owner's image, "watch later", etc. https://imgur.com/a/qeRAScv